# Anyone have any problems installing OpenSSH via Cygwin on Vista 64 Bit?

Tags: cygwin, vista64, openssh

I was able to install the sshd service (after A LOT of problems), and was able to ssh on the machine that I installed it on by saying ssh hao@192.168.1.3 AND ssh localhost. However, all other machines on my local area network could not ssh to it. I checked and port 22 was indeed open, and SSH was listening on that port.

Anyone gone through an install like this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This site is for programming questions only, not general computer support. I suggest trying the cygwin mailing lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are the Vista firewall is active. Open control panel, search for firewall, and turn it off entirely and see if external connections work. If they do, then you gotta figure out how to open port 22 inbound, which should be pretty easy but without a Vista machine handy I can't tell you exactly.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I think that it was off. I double checked to make sure that Windows Firewall allowed port 22, and so did my router. Still no work...Something must have been wrong with the installation since many people have trouble in Vista, but there were no search results on google.

Comment: Hang on a sec, are you trying to connect from the internet? If you intend to connect to 192.168.1.3 from the internet at large you're going to need to set up a nat port-forward as well.

Try connecting from another PC on your local network, with an ip address in the same subnet, like 192.168.1.2

Comment: Nah, I got it, thanks for your help. I was trying to connect via LAN, but I realized that I forgot that my NOD32 also was a firewall, not just anti-virus since I got the smart security suite. I opened the port on that and it works fine now :) I just need to figure out why it auto kicks me upon login